I have a Missing required parameter error for [Route:rooms.update]
This error occurs to me when I want to edit a room, I don't know if the error is in controller or in web paths
 <form action="{{ route('habitaciones.update', $habitacion->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

// Rutas para las habitaciones
Route::get('/habitaciones', [HabitacionController::class, 'index'])->name('habitaciones.index');
Route::get('/habitaciones/crear', [HabitacionController::class, 'create'])->name('habitaciones.create');
Route::post('/habitaciones', [HabitacionController::class, 'store'])->name('habitaciones.store');
Route::get('/habitaciones/editar/{habitacion}', [HabitacionController::class, 'edit'])->name('habitaciones.edit');
Route::put('/habitaciones/{habitacion}', [HabitacionController::class, 'update'])->name('habitaciones.update');
Route::delete('/habitaciones/{habitacion}', [HabitacionController::class, 'destroy'])->name('habitaciones.destroy');

ya intente ajustar el edit.blade y web.php

I didn't quite get that. Can you provide more details?


are you sure $habitacion->id has an actual id?, 2, try to change it to an array ['habitacion' => $habitacion->id]


Since you defined your route like this:
Route::put('/habitaciones/{habitacion}', [HabitacionController::class, 'update'])->name('habitaciones.update');

You always need to specifically pass the named parameter when calling route() helper:
 <form action="{{ route('habitaciones.update', ['habitacion' => $habitacion->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

You can find some more info on official documentation
